# How to hide inner fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager

I have been reading that to hide a fragment the recommended way is to do it from the parent activity using the fragment transaction.
But if we have:
ActivityA --> Fragment1
And Fragment1 has inner fragments using the `getChildFragmentManager`.
How should I remove the inner fragments? Trying from `ActivityA` I am getting `null` when trying to do `findFragmentByTag`.
Should I be doing it from `Fragment1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since `Fragment1` is a "parent" of inner fragments, it is responsible for them. You can perform transactions on its child fragments via child fragment manager.

Comment: Is there an API to get `Fragment1` like there is `getActivity`? Or am I supposed to pass a reference?

Comment: There is `getParentFragment()` method. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment%28%29